# Check 'effective permissions', 'effective access' from command-line, Windows/NTFS

Tags: windows, active-directory, permissions, command-line-interface, file-permissions

How do I mimic Advanced Security Settings 'Effective Access' tab in command line (Win10 notably)? Prefer built-in tools, I'm about to evaluate if [sysinternals AccessChk](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/accesschk) can accomplish this

icacls only shows domain groups given permission to this folder, so how can I check an individual user? A logical answer might be use `net user gregg /domain` to validate if the user-in-question is part of the domain group given permission to that folder. Would those two steps give all the info 'Effective Access' would give?

Background info:

- I'm a sysadmin with two domain accounts (one normal/limited, one domain admin). So when someone says they can't access a file I have to remote into server to get admin access to use 'effective access' which is kind of inconvenient. Can I somehow do that with RSAT tools?
- Our network drive folders each have unique permissions that used domain user groups. Management staff sometimes move files from a secure location to a less-secure (everyone has access) folder, but the secure permissions follow it causing trouble for other staff. Permissions are handled differently when you copy vs move/cut (see [kb310316](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/310316/how-permissions-are-handled-when-you-copy-and-move-files-and-folders) or [this blog post](http://blog.johndwhite.net/ntfs-permissions-and-the-difference-between-copy-move/)), but good luck explaining that to an end user since I've just slowly grasped the concept

*Related questions:*

- *[StackOverflow: How to get effective permission of a NTFS file using command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6851417/1575219)*
- *[Superuser: Windows: List files and their permissions (access) in command line](https://superuser.com/questions/364083/windows-list-files-and-their-permissions-access-in-command-line/364085)*

Comment: If your users have Full Control over any NTFS directories, remove it. At most, they should be set to Modify. Assuming you set up your top-level directories so that permissions are inherited to all child files and folders, any such moves should not create this problem with odd permissions. *by default* files will inherit permissions at the destination folder. If you're copying files via xcopy or robocopy, stop using `xcopy /x /o` or `robocopy /sec`, `/dats` or `/copyall` switches

Comment: Also, for having to use your admin account to connect to a separate system, this is actually best practice. Look up "golden ticket exploits" to give yourself a fright. However, connecting to multiple boxes can be painful - if you have enough systems to maintain, perhaps consider asking for a "jump server" that you can log into with your admin account to maintain other systems

Answer (score 2):

My preferred method for doing this is to use a non-native PowerShell Module [NTFSSecurity](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/NTFSSecurity/4.2.3) available in the PowerShell Gallery.

You can install the module from most modern Windows Powershell windows by running

```
Install-Module -Name NTFSSecurity -RequiredVersion 4.2.3
```

In order to retrieve the Effective Access, you would run the following command:

```
Get-NTFSEffectiveAccess -Path \\path\to\UNC\file -Account <samaccountname>
```

It will work on local paths as well; the output takes the following format:

```
 Path: \\path\to\UNC\file (Inheritance disabled)

Account      Access Rights     Applies to      Type     IsInherited     InheritedFrom
-------      -------------     ----------      ----     -----------     -------------
DOMAIN\user  FullControl       ThisFolderOnly  Allow    False
```

Comment: I just want to endorse this module as being highly preferable to trying to roll your own, even with general NTFS permissions management in Powershell